# How can I apply a Thunderbird filter periodically?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to achieve the following using Thunderbird:

**Apply filter when: Periodically (e.g. every hour)**

[image]

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this hourly, and not when the mail is fetched?

Comment: I want to copy a new message to another folder and mark it as read in the primary folder.

Comment: I think if you create a filter like @SPRBRN has stated it achieves what you want since it processes on each new mail. But maybe there is a way not sure how.

Comment: Why do you want to copy a message? Is this some kind of ticket system or todo-list?

Comment: @SPRBRN please take a look at my edit. Does that make sense?

Comment: This edit explains what, not why. This looks to me like you want to forward incoming messages from account 1 to account 2, and then mark them as "read" in account 1. https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Thunderbird/How-do-I-set-up-automatic-forwarding-of-all-email-incoming/m-p/861002 *** Still: why???

Comment: To have a backup and to be able to respond to these emails from my Gmail inbox.